# Dot Product of Gradient and Constant Vector

Tags: vector-analysis

Is

$\vec \nabla \cdot \vec A $

$\mbox{where } \vec\nabla  = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat i + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\hat j + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\hat k$

$\mbox{where } \vec A = \mbox{constant vector}$

$ = 0\mbox{?}$

Is there a proof somewhere that shows this?

Comment: When you say $\vec A$ is constant vector, do you mean constant vector field? Why not just use the definition of partial derivatives?

Comment: This is called the divergence of $A$. But $\vec\nabla=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x})\ne\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

Comment: A derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I edited my question the correct notation.

Comment: This is not a dot product, it is a notation. It means the sum of the derivatives of the components of A. If those components are constant then this sum is zero.